# MySql JOIN table results from one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an e-commerce site (MySql / PHP) where I need to get some results across two joined tables. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
Table: product[
product_id,
other_irrelevant_stuff,
etc.
]

Table: product_to_category[
product_id,
category_id
]
```

Products may have multiple categories. I am using `product p LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)`. I need to get results for products that have two particular categories assigned to them.

Obviously, if I use `p2c.category_id = 1 AND p2c.category_id = 2` I get no results because there will not be a single line item that will match these criteria. If I use `p2c.category_id = 1 OR p2c.category_id = 2` I get all results from both categories (ALL of `category_id = 1` and ALL of `category_id = 2`) which I don't want. I only want to get products that have BOTH `category_id 1` AND `category_id 2`.

I'm usually pretty good at this, but maybe I'm just having a brain fart. Any ideas out there?

Comment: `product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_to_category WHERE p2c.category_id = 1) AND p2c.category_id = 2`

Comment: Thanks David, this worked exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work using `group by` and `count` with `distinct`:

```
select p.product_id
from product p
    join product_to_category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pc.category_id in (1,2)
group by p.product_id
having count(distinct pc.category_id) = 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff6e/1)

Comment: This very well may work in many cases as it did in the SQL fiddle demo, but my actual query was way more complex so this didn't quite work for my application. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: This should work if you join with it as a subquery in your more complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following...

```
select distinct tab1.product_id

from product tab1

join product_to_category tab2 on tab1.product_id = tab2.product_id

where tab2.category_id in (1,2)

group by tab1.product_id;
```

Try this, your problem will be solved.

Comment: This returns products that are in either category. He wants only products that are in BOTH categories.